# Dynamically create checkbox in angular reactive form from api call

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

The issue I'm facing is that I want to create a list of checkboxes from an API response.

I was able to render the checkboxes with example I was following with static values but not when populating array with values from the API.

This is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtmlms

Please note that the static values can be safely removed if you know what I need to do in order to render the dynamic values.

Comment: What object you want in end

Comment: @MustafaKunwa checkbox list of id and sizeName http://prntscr.com/q85jdg thx for helping!

Comment: Will this do https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-at24ye

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, please write that as an answer and I'll select it! Thanks again

Comment: if You need data you can call valueChange

Comment: i have updated your stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ri8vit, you can check this may this helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shared Stackblitz Look into it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-at24ye

Comment: some explanation is good, add some code snippet and explain it, it will helps people a lot

Comment: @MustafaKunwa I'm getting this error when including your solution in the project http://prntscr.com/q864iv do you know what can be the issue? Thanks

Comment: have you checked form has some value Because the form is created after server call till that time form was empty.

Comment: @MustafaKunwa still the same output, do you want to connect via teamviewer for a minute and see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Create Stackblitz and share

Comment: It's actually the same code as in the stackblitz, only that the form is displayed in modal window, does that make some difference? Thx @MustafaKunwa

Comment: @MustafaKunwa the musicpreferences array is null when trying to map the result to the array http://prntscr.com/q86s6n

Comment: add this code  get musicPreferences() {
    return this.customerForm.get('musicPreferences') as FormArray;
  }

Comment: make sure which stackblitz you are following there are 2 of them and this code is in second stackbliztz

Comment: I have that as a function in the  code http://prntscr.com/q86vpd should I call that somewhere else?

Comment: If you are following solution properly I don't think there is any Issue

Comment: I've setup a breakpoint and the line for getting the musicPreferences is not being triggered before the api call, do you know why? @MustafaKunwa thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203889/discussion-between-laziale-and-mustafa-kunwa).

Comment: I downvoted this because on SatckOverflow, the etiquette is to explain the answer to the question, not provide a link to a shady example that (depending on if it gets updated or not ;)) is not even properly formatted.

Comment: @JoshuaMichaelCalafell explanation is there in comments if you check properly