# Getting value of checkbox that are generated from API response in Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to generate the angular reactive form of checkboxes that is generated from API response. I followed this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244266/dynamically-create-checkbox-in-angular-reactive-form-from-api-call) and this [StackBlits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gt5kkc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) demo.
But the issue is I'm getting array of true false. Instead I need actual value of that checkbox.
Actual output:

```
[true, flase ...]
```

Expected output:

```
[value-1, value-2 ...]
```

I tried to set the value attribute to the checkbox but it still gives me the array of booleans like

```
[true, false ...]
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ww9jge?file=src%2Fmain.ts Hi, Can you please share your more code and lets discuss. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.